# Need a link/URL to a raw source file in Azure Dev Ops (ADO)

Tags: azure-devops

We recently migrated from Bitbucket to ADO and one of our platforms requires a link that will return the raw file for its deployment process. Bitbucket has a "raw" link available when viewing source files in the web UI, but I haven't found anything like that in ADO, the closest thing is a download link, but I need a link that just simply returns/displays the raw source file contents, not with a download dialog box. Is this possible?

Comment: are you trying to write an azure pipeline which clones some repo ?

Comment: Have you tried the [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) API already?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using the following in the api URL got me what I need:

```
_apis/sourceProviders/TfsGit
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/source-providers/get-file-contents?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).